# What are the differences between Windows Defender and Windows Intune Endpoint Protection and SCCM Endpoint Protection?

Tags: sccm, windows-8, sccm-2012, anti-virus

What are the functional differences between Windows Defender and Windows Intune Endpoint Protection and SCCM Endpoint Protection, apart from methods of management, if any?

(I am referring to the Windows 8 version of Windows Defender, which I understand to include the functionality of Windows Security Essentials)

Comment: Pretty sure they are roughly identical, with some central management features bolted on the latter two...but have no real proof of that besides having used them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Defender pre-Windows 8 is a weak tool targeted at specific threats. It's not a full fledge AV, which is why Microsoft release Microsoft Security Essentials for home users. In Windows 8, Defender has MSE functionality rolled into it.

Endpoint for SCCM and Intune are functionally similar to MSE, except that it allows for more granular centralized management *and* reporting, which can be done either through Intune or SCCM. The SCCM and Intune versions are identical, except one is managed through a cloud-based Intune instance and one is managed through an on-prem SCCM instance.

So, basically, when talking about Windows 8 - all three are similar. It comes down to the management and reporting, or lack thereof.

Comment: So does that mean that the threat analysis is identical across all of them?

Comment: As far as I am aware, they all use the same definitions. Intune and SCCM's endpoint packages are absolutely identical. I *believe* Defender also follow that, but I'm not 100% sure.